# Storybook with web components - changing arguments dynamically on code

Tags: javascript, web-component, storybook, custom-element, storybook-addon

I have a modal component and I'm writing the story for it. It looks something like this:

```js
import { Story, Meta } from '@storybook/html';

export default {
  title: 'Components/Modal',
  argTypes: {
    open: {
      name: 'Opened',
      control: 'boolean'
    },
  },
  args: {
    open: false,
  }
} as Meta;

const Template: Story = (args) => {
  return `
    <my-modal open="${args.open}">
      Some example content inside the modal
    </my-modal>
  `;
};

export const Modal: Story = Template.bind({});
```

I have the arg `open` on the controls and I can change its value to true and the modal shows. But I would like the story to have a button and when it's clicked, the modal shows.
I can't find a way to do this in the current version of Storybook for web components.

I've seen there are some hooks available for React (`import { useArgs } from '@storybook/api';`) that allows you to change the arguments value dynamically but I can't see how to do this for web components?

Any helps will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question, then I tried to use the `useArgs` hook and... it works!

```
import { useArgs } from '@storybook/client-api';
import type { Story, Meta } from '@storybook/web-components';
import { html } from 'lit';

import type { DialogSize } from './dialog';
import './dialog';

const meta: Meta = {
  title: 'Components/Dialog',
  argTypes: {
    open: {
      control: 'boolean',
    },
    size: {
      control: 'select',
      options: ['small', 'default', 'large'],
    },
    overlayClick: {
      action: 'm-overlay-click',
      table: {
        disable: true,
      },
    },
  },
};

export default meta;

export const Playground: Story<{
  open: boolean;
  size: DialogSize;
  overlayClick: () => void;
}> = ({ size, overlayClick }) => {
  const [{ open }, updateArgs] = useArgs();

  function handleOpenClick() {
    updateArgs({ open: true });
  }

  function handleOverlayClick() {
    updateArgs({ open: false });
    overlayClick();
  }

  return html`
    <div>
      <button type="button" @click=${handleOpenClick}>Open Dialog</button>
      <m-dialog ?open=${open} size=${size} @m-overlay-click=${handleOverlayClick}>
        <m-dialog-body>Content</m-dialog-body>
      </m-dialog>
    </div>
  `;
};

Playground.args = {
  open: false,
  size: 'default',
};
```

I'm using StoryBook 6.5 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Just add that button to the template:

```js
import { Story, Meta } from '@storybook/html';

export default {
  title: 'Components/Modal',
  argTypes: {
    open: {
      name: 'Opened',
      control: 'boolean'
    },
  },
  args: {
    open: false,
  }
} as Meta;

const Template: Story = (args) => {
  return `
    <button 
      type="button" 
      onclick="this.nextElementSibling.open = !this.nextElementSibling.open">
        Toggle Modal
    </button>
    <my-modal .open=${args.open}>
      Some example content inside the modal
    </my-modal>
  `;
};

export const Modal: Story = Template.bind({});
```

Also, for boolean attributes - if implemented properly -
you should work with the property (prefix it in the template with a `.`) rather than the attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)
I actually had something similar, just adding a <script> tag with the code to do that.
But I was looking for something more "integrated" with Storybook, the same way the useArgs hook does if you are using React. So you are actually modifying the argument value. But I guess there is no way to do it with web components :(

Comment: I have no clue about React or `useArgs` or what those hooks even are. I prefer to take the DOM route whenever it's available; I hate to rely on tooling to get things done, and I'd never consider installing an add-on or sth the like to do it in a *"more integrated way"*. Integration into tools imo is a bad thing; it makes you even more reliant on those tools, on those add-ons being maintained and not deprecated (as so many Storbook addons/features are) which over time you will **never** manage to keep up to date.

Comment: If there is no better solution available, why not mark this the answer so others find it?

Answer (score -2):

Doing that with **all native code** isn't rocket science...

```html
<my-dialog id="DIALOG" open>
  Hello *Native* Web Components world!
</my-dialog>

<button onclick="DIALOG.open()">OPEN</button>

<script>
  customElements.define("my-dialog", class extends HTMLElement {
    static get observedAttributes() {
      return ["open"];
    }
    constructor() {
      super() // sets and returns 'this'
        .attachShadow({mode:"open"}) // sets and return this.shadowRoot
        .innerHTML = `<dialog><slot></slot><button>Close</button></dialog>`;
      this.dialog = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("dialog");
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      this.onclick = () => this.close(); // or attach to button
    }
    attributeChangedCallback(name,oldValue,newValue) {
      this.open();
    }
    open() {
      this.dialog.showModal(); // or .show()
    }
    close() {
      this.dialog.close();
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was asking about Storybook.